# Prevent iTunes 12 for Windows from stopping podcast update

Tags: itunes, windows, podcasts

There are some podcasts that I listen to infrequently, but when I do, I want to listen to *all* of the previous episodes. After I stop listening for a while, however, iTunes stops updating automatically. How can I ensure that it always automatically keeps downloading new episodes of these podcasts?

This is the same issue described in the question ["Stop iTunes from automatically stopping podcast downloads"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11012/stop-itunes-from-automatically-stopping-podcast-downloads) for an older version of iTunes. There weren't any good solutions for Windows then. Is there a solution for iTunes 12?

Comment: This question is a direct result of the suggestions to my question on Meta, ["If an old question wasn't answered, is there a good way to bump it?"](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2290/if-an-old-question-wasnt-answered-is-there-a-good-way-to-bump-it/2291)

Comment: I haven't had this problem with the current version -- maybe this "feature" was removed?  Maybe I have it set differently... not sure.

Comment: No it's still there, even as of now. It's annoying as hell.